# Setting environment variables for multiple apps at the same time in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables

I'd like to set env. vars for multiple apps at the same time. Something like this:

`heroku config:set VAR='whatever' --app heroku-app-1, heroku-app-2` …or…

`heroku config:set VAR='whatever' --app heroku-app-1 --app heroku-app-2`?

Is this possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way with the standard API client, but the plugin [heroku-wildcards](https://github.com/tpope/heroku-wildcards) adds this functionality.

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/tpope/heroku-wildcards.git
```

Then you can run

```
heroku config:set VAR='whatever' --app heroku-app-1,heroku-app-2
```

Or

```
heroku config:set VAR='whatever' --app heroku-app-*
```